# bash script question [: too many arguments

Tags: bash

**This is the bash script I tested :**

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ 8 -gt 6 ] && [ 10 -eq 10 ];
then
    echo "Conditions are true"
fi
```

but get a error  **[: too many arguments**.

I tried adding two square brackets, the error is **syntax error near unexpected token `[['**

```
#!/bin/bash
    if [[ 8 -gt 6 ]] && [[ 10 -eq 10 ]];
    then
        echo "Conditions are true"
    fi
```

I modified the code to be like this :

```
if [ 8 -gt 6 ];
then
    echo "Conditions are true"
fi
```

This is okay .
How to solve this problem? thanks.

Comment: It works for me, what Bash version are you using?

Comment: Check the line endings of your file. Your file is likely using DOS line endings `CRLF` but bash requires UNIX line endings `LF`.

Comment: @LéaGris, I've run `sed -i -z 's/\n$//;s/\n/\r\n/g'` on the source to turn it into what DOS would deal with, but the error is `/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`, not `[: too many arguments`. Maybe it's not a line ending problem?

Comment: @LéaGris  I pasted the code into notepad++ and found that the newline character is CRLF, maybe for this reason. thank you

Comment: @Enlico I googled and found   "\r" shows "^M"  in the UNIX environment.